# How to create search engine in leaflet map using apache solr?

Tags: solr, leaflet, marker

I'm building an app that lets user find vacation rental from map. I've several data in my leaflet application. So my question is about:

1. How to make a search engine from the map itself that search the marker id(and content of it)?

   In this case, i wish to create a search bar outside the map which user can search any places and the result should be appear in the map in the form of marker pointer which indicate the result instead of list of result in list view.
2. How to make the marker appear when user query the result

Answer (score 0):

Your use case have a solution In **Kibana-6** with elasticsearch , there is a lucene bar search which search interactively your data.

this is my work on **nyc-cabs-data** :
[image: Kibana Dashboard with maps]

as you can see in the lucene bar i search the field **total_amount** which is a column in my csv